# How to implement an actualisation once i've added items to my viewmodel's Observablecollection?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am new to silverlight so bear with me.. i have a view model in which i have 3 `ObservableCollection`s of 3 classes (inherited from `INotificyPropertyChanged`). One of this classes is "Favorites" . In a child pivot page(of the main panorama view), i modify the favorites (i add one to the database etc.).

How can i "update" the view of the main panorama view? is it sufficient to add the new favorite object to the ObservableCollection or do i need to implement some new actions? From what i understood, the views are active, so if i modify an element (even one linked though `Binding`) it should update. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything if you add or remove an item to an `ObservableCollection`, the UI will show this new item automatically. However, if you modify your underlying data object, the UI won't be updated unless your object have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You can take a look at [this post](http://weblogs.asp.net/joelvarty/archive/2008/11/17/silverlight-databinding-the-observable-collection.aspx) or [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SLListVsOCollections.aspx).